# Error when saving updated email Category in VBA Outlook - "The function cannot be performed because the message has changed"

Tags: vba, outlook

I save email attachements to local disk and add a category to the email to mark them that the attachemt was already saved.  The code:

```
Public Sub SaveAttachToDisk(ByRef itm As Outlook.MailItem)
    If itm.MessageClass <> "IPM.Note" Then
        Exit Sub 
    End If
    Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
    For Each objAtt In itm.attachments
      objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolderFull  
    Next
    itm.Categories = itm.Categories & "; Autosaved."
    itm.Save
End Sub
```

Unfortunately every couple hundred times it gets an error  ["The function cannot be performed because the message has changed"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/deWUT.png).
Do you know what is the reason? I do not change anything in the email but save the attachements and add the Category.

Comment: Where and when do you run that code?

Comment: Assuming this is in a Run a script rule, I suggest the [ItemAdd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.itemadd) event may be more reliable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a non-programming issue in Outlook. You may find a bunch of similar posts over the internet, for example, take a look at the following:

- ["The operation cannot be performed because the message has been changed."](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/the-operation-cannot-be-performed-because-the/ba4fa59e-0813-4874-b122-10bcf6e586af)
- [How to: Fix "The operation cannot be performed because the message has changed" in Outlook 2013](https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/132555-fix-the-operation-cannot-be-performed-because-the-message-has-changed-in-outlook-2013#:%7E:text=Go%20to%20Options%20%3E%20Mail%20%3E%20Conversation,has%20resolved%20the%20issue%20here.)